# How to concatenate variables to form a datetime object in a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a condition where a db table `appointment` consists of 2 columns viz. `date` (datatype is date) and `hour` (datatype is int (0-23)). Those columns represent the date of appointment request(date) and hour of appointment seeked (hour).
I need to display every appointment requests which lies ahead of current time. 
If the `date` was a datetime object we could do :

```
Select * from appointment where `date`-current_timestamp()>0
```

Since I have a date value separate and hour value separate how can I join them to make a datetime value so that something like ``date`+`hour`+":00:00"-current_timestamp()>0`
would be valid. I tried this concatenation by + but it didnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to combine `date` and `time`.  Another is to do two comparisons:

```
select a.*
from appointment a
where a.date > curdate() or
      (a.date = curdate() and a.time > curtime());
```